# To grep particular job id from a file

Tags: unix, grep

I tried the usual grep command, got 4 matches.

```
grep job_ import.err
20/04/27 12:46:30 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1587332046499_7576
20/04/27 12:46:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1587332046499_7576
20/04/27 12:46:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1587332046499_7576 running in uber mode : false
20/04/27 12:46:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1587332046499_7576 completed successfully
```

I need to extract only the job id i.e. `job_1587332046499_7576` from the file only once. What is the command?

Answer (score 1):

If the job id only contains digits and underscores, try this:

```
$ grep -Eo 'job_[0-9_]+' import.err | sort -u
job_1587332046499_7576
```